# react useEffect how to determine when complete for multiple async tasks in loop

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, state, use-effect

I have a weird scenerio where i have a useEffect that is retreiveing data from a server, then setting the state in my app. The thing that is weird is that I have it doing this in a for loop for the number of devices it detects. The data size for each iteration ranges quite a bit and causes weirdness in the async reaction. This is ok as it is optimal but how can I figure out when the useEffect has completed. I have tried this but due to random data sizes for each iteration, they come in at different times and I can't log it properly...

```
useEffect(() => {
    // this grabs all historical data only if the indexDB does NOT exist
    if (indexDBExists.userExists === false && devices.devices !== null) {
        console.log("getAllHistoricalData() mounted")
            let valueArray = []
            let keyArray = []
            for (let i=0; i<devices.devices.length; i++){
                getAllHistoricalData(devices.devices[i]).then((res) => {
                    valueArray.push(res)
                    keyArray.push(devices.devices[i])
                    if (i === devices.devices.length - 1){
                        const counter = allHistoricalData.done + 1
                            setAllHistoricalData({values: valueArray, keys: keyArray, done: counter})
                        }else{
                            const counter = allHistoricalData.done + 1
                            setAllHistoricalData({values: valueArray, keys: keyArray, done: counter})
                        }
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            }
    }
    return () => {
        console.log("getAllHistoricalData() un-mounted")
    };
}, [indexDBExists.user, devices.devices]);
```

As you can see, I have tried creating a counter that I can use later to compare to the length of the devices.devices. However this doesn't works because the counter vairable gets created before the async task and is not up to date when it comes time to setState. How can I figure out a way to know when this useEffect has completed?

Comment: You can do this.

```javascript
const fetchTasks = devices.devices.map(i => getAllHistoricalData(i));
Promise.all(fetchTasks)
  .then(function (res) {
    //...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // ...
  });
```

Comment: Ah. I think this is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: One question though, I have an array of keys that lets me know which task has been sent back. Will this always send back the same order or will it vary based on time to fetch?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter. I adjusted my backend to send the key with it.

Comment: Yes, The order is the same. You can find the specific task by index.

Comment: Good to know, no need to send keys then. Thanks